# Can´t find installed but expired certificate?

Tags: c#, .net, certificate

One of my certificates have been expired. This makes the following code fail :

```
 X509Store store = new X509Store(settings.CertificateStore, settings.CertificateLocation);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, settings.Thumbprint, true);
            store.Close();

            if (certs.Count > 0)
            {
                LogHandler.Instance.Log(LogLev.Info, $"UseSecureConnection > Location:{settings.CertificateLocation}, Store:{settings.CertificateStore}, Thumbprint:{settings.Thumbprint}");
                _serviceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(settings.CertificateLocation,
                settings.CertificateStore, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, settings.Thumbprint);

            }
            else
                throw new Exception("Could not find certificate with thumbprint " + settings.Thumbprint);
```

This codes worked great uptil certificate got expired.

How do i fetch it even if its expired?

Comment: `store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, settings.Thumbprint, false)` should do it.

Comment: You are correct, you whould make this the answer. Thanks! And yes, I should have checked the parameters better :(

Comment: Yes, I know that feeling well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, settings.Thumbprint, false)
```

should do it. [The last parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2collection.find?view=netframework-4.7.2) is `validOnly`.